How to have Pygrib read in grib2 from website
I am trying to read in this file: https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/forecast/202212/20221216/nam_218_20221216_1200_000.grb2 for an experiment using Google Colab. The link leads you to download a .grb2 dataset from a NOAA website.
However, I get this error in my code:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py:89: UserWarning: pyproj unable to set database path.
  _pyproj_global_context_initialize()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-54c5584b42fe> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 gribpath='https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/forecast/202212/20221216/nam_218_20221216_1200_000.grb2'
      9 # grbs = pygrib.open(gribpath)
---> 10 grbs = pygrib.open(gribpath).read()
     11 # gpath=gribpath.read()
     12 # grb = pygrib.fromstring(gpath)

src/pygrib/_pygrib.pyx in pygrib._pygrib.open.__cinit__()

OSError: [Errno could not open %s] https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/forecast/202212/20221216/nam_218_20221216_1200_000.grb2

The code I have is
import time
import numpy
import pygrib

gribpath='https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/forecast/202212/20221216/nam_218_20221216_1200_000.grb2'
# grbs = pygrib.open(gribpath)
grbs = pygrib.open(gribpath).read()
# gpath=gribpath.read()
# grb = pygrib.fromstring(gpath)
print (grbs.keys())

It seems to have to do with the source as in most cases it would work if being downloaded onto the laptop. However, I cannot use Anaconda or connect my Google Drive for this due to work.
I tried something based on Loading a GRIB from the web in Python without saving the file locally in
import time
import numpy
import pygrib
import urllib
# import cfgrib
# import xarray as xr
# import requests,json

gribdata='https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/forecast/202212/20221216/nam_218_20221216_1200_000.grb2'
data = urllib.request.urlopen(gribdata)
# grbs = pygrib.open(gribpath)
grbs = pygrib.open(data)
# gpath=gribpath.read()
# grb = pygrib.fromstring(gpath)
print (grbs.keys())

but gave me:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py:89: UserWarning: pyproj unable to set database path.
  _pyproj_global_context_initialize()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d31a1c34cf66> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 data = urllib.request.urlopen(gribdata)
     11 # grbs = pygrib.open(gribpath)
---> 12 grbs = pygrib.open(data)
     13 # gpath=gribpath.read()
     14 # grb = pygrib.fromstring(gpath)

src/pygrib/_pygrib.pyx in pygrib._pygrib.open.__cinit__()

TypeError: expected bytes, HTTPResponse found


I believe I had resolved the issue with this:
import time
import numpy as np
import pygrib
import urllib
# import cfgrib
# import xarray as xr
# import requests,json

print('Assign URL to gribdata variable...')
gribdata='https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/north-american-mesoscale-model/access/forecast/202212/20221216/nam_218_20221216_1200_000.grb2'
print('...Complete!')

print('urlopen gribdata...')
data = urllib.request.urlopen(gribdata).read()
print('...urlopen Complete!')

# grbs = pygrib.open(gribpath)
print ("PyGrib open")
grbs = pygrib.open(data)
print ("Task complete")
# gpath=gribpath.read()
# grb = pygrib.fromstring(gpath)
# print (grbs.keys())

Although it keeps killing the code due to the size of the file.
